# Dependency problem (pefile -> future) during pip installing pyinstaller

Tags: python, dependencies, pyinstaller

I cannot install pyinstaller because of some dependecy conflicts. Start and the and of the log below...
Using Python 3.7.9, pip 21.3.1, windows 7 64, instaling from cmd line as administrator

Log:

```
Collecting pyinstaller
Using cached pyinstaller-4.7-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6
Using cached pyinstaller_hooks_contrib-2021.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (215 kB)
Collecting altgraph
Using cached altgraph-0.17.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python\spyder\pkgs (from pyinstaller) (59.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in c:\python\spyder\pkgs (from pyinstaller) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\python\spyder\pkgs (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Collecting pefile>=2017.8.1
Using cached pefile-2021.9.3.tar.gz (72 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting future
Using cached future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Using cached future-0.18.1.tar.gz (828 kB)
 ...

 ...
  Using cached pyinstaller-2.0.zip (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Using cached pyinstaller-2.0.tar.bz2 (2.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

The conflict is caused by:
    pefile 2021.9.3 depends on future
   ...
    pefile 2017.8.1 depends on future

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Comment: `Using cached pyinstaller-2.0.zip`  ... try to purge pip's cache: `pip cache purge` and install again.

Comment: you can download/install a specific version which is compatible with the installed one

Comment: Not working. I can see that there is no problem with pyinstaller but with dependencies.
pip is looking for modules future and src.future which are needed for pefile.
Why is problem with future i.e why pip dosen't see them?

Comment: Actually it sees future but it doesnt see src.future.  what is this there is no src.future on PyPI and ther is a little on the internet... this is in setup.py for future:
import src.future
VERSION = src.future.__version__
DESCRIPTION = "Clean single-source support for Python 3 and 2"
LONG_DESC = src.future.__doc__
AUTHOR = "Ed Schofield"
AUTHOR_EMAIL = "ed@pythoncharmers.com"
URL="https://python-future.org"
LICENSE = "MIT"
KEYWORDS = "future past python3 migration futurize backport six 2to3 modernize pasteurize 3to2"
...